# How to split list without losing the head of the list

Tags: list, function, haskell, split

I'm trying to create a function that takes a list and returns two lists by splitting the list in half. Right now I have it so it splits the list in half like I want, but the head of the list is removed.

```
halve       :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
halve []    = ([],[])
halve [x]   = ([x],[])
halve (x:xs) =  (splitAt half xs)
    where len = length xs
          half = len `div` 2
```

If I call the function with `halve [1,2,3,4]` the output is `([2],[3,4])`
I would like the output to include x like `([1,2],[3,4])`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you want your solution to be maximally lazy? E.g., do you want `halve (1:2:3:4:undefined)` to be `(1:2:undefined, undefined:undefined:undefined)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a reference to the entir elist, so:

```
halve :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
halve []  = ([],[])
halve [x] = ([x],[])
halve xs  = splitAt half xs
  where half = length xs `div` 2
```

Your program will however run for endlessly for an infinite amount of time. You should look for a recursive method to tackle this.

The second line with `halve [x] = ([x], [])` also seems counter-intuitive, since for `halve [1,4,2]`, it will split as `([1], [4,2])` and thus your `splitAt` currently favors putting an element in the second item of the 2-tuple.